# CouchDB replication using a selector

Tags: javascript, url, replication, pouchdb

Trying to create CouchDB replication using a selector
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3XzH.png
but the request returns an error "unknown builtin filter name".

Request URL is 'https://example.com/schemes/_changes?timeout=25000&style=all_docs&filter=_selector%2F_selector&since=0&limit=4'

Why is the selector duplicated (_selector%2F_selector) in the request?

```
public startReplication = async (): Promise<void> => {
this.database.sync(null, {
  pull: {
    live: true,
    retry: true,
    filter: undefined,
    selector: {
      selector: {
        author: '456w346456',
      },
      sort: ['modified', 'asc'],
      fields: ['firstField', 'secondField']
    },
    batch_size: 4
  },
  push: {
    live: true,
    retry: true,
  },
});
```

};

Comment: in your screenshot, there is a 'selector' in 'selector' - that's probably the reason for the duplicate ;-)

Comment: unfortunately, that's not the point)

Comment: did you read the selector docs? https://docs.couchdb.org/en/3.2.0/api/database/find.html#selector-syntax
(selector in selector does not seem to make any sense IMHO)

Comment: @PavelTasits you need to provide a lot more information, for example how the URL provided maps to the allegedly correct JSON for the query.  Also, please do not post images; beyond dead links, it prevents those with visual impairments from participating.

Comment: @RamblinRose, thanks for the advice about image placement. I add this selector to the sync method of the database in the pull object. And after the synchronization starts, I get an error in Google Devtools, which I described.

Comment: This looks like pouchDB?

Comment: Also, what version of couchDB is hosting?

Comment: @RamblinRose, Yes, I was wrong. this is PouchDB. CouchDB version is 3.2.0

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like:

```
public startReplication = async (): Promise<void> => {
this.database.sync(null, {
  pull: {
    live: true,
    retry: true,
    filter: undefined,
    selector: {
      author: '456w346456',
    },
    batch_size: 4
  },
  push: {
    live: true,
    retry: true,
  },
});
```

The `selector` should just be an object describing the query that is to be applied to each change in the changes feed. In your example, you have a nested `selector` object within the selector.

Also your `sort` and `fields` keys are irrelevant here: it's not like the querying mechanism - you can't specify the sort order or which fields are to be returned.

Comment: Thanks for advice! So  I can't sort objects coming from CouchDB using the selector?

Comment: @PavelTasits No

Comment: Not during replication/sync, no.

Comment: @RamblinRose, Glynn Bird, thank you for your help!!